What does this Lemon ad scene mean in Madmen?
In the TV show, Madmen, ep 3 season 1, Draper rides a train and runs into someone who knows him by a different name.
Draper becomes very uncomfortable after being called by a different name and the train conductor comes up from behind Draper, seeing a VW Lemon ad and smiles.
What does this scene mean?

Draper becomes uncomfortable as he has something to hide from his past. What does it have anything to do this VW Lemon ad and why does the conductor smile after he sees the same ad?



Because it's an amazing advert and a professional ad-man like Draper probably pitched (and lost) the VW account.

Er, it's called 'Mad Men' (two words).
